# HTML Checkbox as a Button - Include Label and Button as clickable area

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, forms

I use bootstrap 3 and a checkbox with a label. I managed to make the label tick off the checkbox when clicked, but the surrounding button design doesn't allow this feature.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary"><form action="link.php"  method="post">
    <label for="jevattend_id">This is the label</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="jevattend" id="jevattend_id" value="1"  onclick="form.submit();"/>
 </form></div>
```

To make that clear have a look at the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/etpq2/

I would like to tick off the box even when just the button is clicked.

Comment: put the label around what you want to have clicked to make the checkbox change state

Comment: The code in the JSFiddle works just fine for me. Clicking the label toggles the checkbox.

Comment: @Quentin "I would like to tick off the box even when just the button is clicked"

Comment: onclick="form.submit(); you can click only once since form is submitted right away, what is your goal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the label around what you want to have clicked to make the checkbox change state. 

In this case just  apply the button class to the label. The form doesn't belong inside the button.

```
<form action="link.php"  method="post">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        This is the label
        <input type="checkbox" name="jevattend" id="jevattend_id" value="1"  onclick="form.submit();"/>
    </label>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etpq2/3/

Comment: exactly what i said to do. you smart

Comment: Congratulations on knowing the same as I do to solve this. Commiserations in not knowing how to answer a question properly.

Answer (score -1):

wrap your label around the input element, makes the whole area clickable, and its better for usability

Comment: are you kidding me....this is the exact same answer as the one that was accepted. ya'll are weak sauce. actually my answer is better because it addresses more topics, like usability. how about you learn web development before you start making comments. also english. go for it.

Comment: No this is not an answer, this is a comment. An answer would include the code that fixes the problem.